# jQuery Ajax test does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, js-test-driver, sinon

I am trying to test a very simple jQuery plugin which simply calls $.ajax method and put its content into a  element. For testing I am using JsTestDriver and Sinon for mocking.

Plugin file looks:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.transfer = function() {

    $.ajax({
        url : 'friends',
    type : 'GET',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(html) {
        console.log("-"+html+"-");
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).html(html);
        console.log("+"+$(this).html()+"+")
    }
});
};
})(jQuery);
```

In theory very simple plugin.

And then I have written a unit test mocking success function:

```
TestCase("Ajax ", {
    'test response' : function () {
        /*:DOC divElement = <div id="container" style="height: 100px;"></div>*/
        sinon.stub(jQuery, "ajax").yieldsTo(
            "success", 'alex');
        $(this.divElement).transfer();
        console.log("*"+$(this.divElement).text()+"*");
    }
});
```

it seems correct too. Then if you execute this test, next lines are printed through console:

```
[LOG] -alex-

[LOG] [object Object]

[LOG] +null+

[LOG] **
```

So success function receives correctly "alex" string. Then $(this) reference is printed, message is set with html() function and when I log previous set value, a null is returned.
And last log message is in test file, where as you can see ajax text is not set.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Because I am sure I am missing something that now I cannot see.

Comment: console.log($(this)); will refer to the ajax object - not the element passed to the plugin

Comment: you are mixing json dataType with strings in test, hard to follow what you are wanting

Answer (score 0):

**Use Synchronous AJAX**

JS Test driver and most testing frameworks I know of have a bit of a problem handling asynchronous javascript, basically the disjointed nature of asynchronous calls screws up the order of test execution (think: test 2 starts executing before test 1 is finished). For this reason try using synchornous ajax calls for the duration of your tests by setting the global async property with [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

```
// Use synchronous AJAX
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async: false});

TestCase("Ajax ", {
    'test1' : function () {
        // etc...
    }
});

// Revert to default
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async: true});
```

Comment: I disagree. js-test-driver supports testing asynchronous functions. It's not what I'd call easy, but it is possible and understandable. As far as I understand it the thread-owner did not have issues with multiple test cases being not in sync but writing ONE test case for a method that uses async behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the [AsyncTestCase](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/AsyncTestCase) that is provided by js-test-driver. It handles asynchronous processes well.

Add your mocked server method to the callbacks in the queue so the test waits until the "server" has been called. Something like this:

```
var AjaxTest = AsyncTestCase('AjaxTest');

AjaxTest.prototype.testResponse = function(queue) {
    /*:DOC divElement = <div id="container" style="height: 100px;"></div>*/

    queue.call('Set up mocked server', function(callbacks) {        
        var serverStub = sinon.stub(jQuery, "ajax").yieldsTo("success", 'alex');
        callbacks.add(serverStub);

        $(this.divElement).transfer();
    });

    queue.call('Make assertions here', function() {
        console.log("*"+$(this.divElement).text()+"*");
    });
};
```

Note: *I haven't tried the code. Hope there are no typos. ;)*